# SharePoint Designer Issue while updating Multiple Line of Text Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am facing one issue in SharePoint Designer workflow. I have a field with type Multiple Line of text "Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)".

Now when I am trying to update this column it is not getting updated but if I am Creating same Column with  "(Plain text)" it is updated but it is showing HTML Tags like `<div> <br />` inside text area.

How can I solve this?

Comment: not getting updated means your are getting some error?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error.